# Illustrator export script, is it possible to remember export setting or save it into the file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I have a file with lot of artworks in it, and when exporting I need a lot of diffrents output formats, as well as .pngs in a specific scale. Whenever there's going to be a need for me to add sth into this file and export it again, I would need to set the export settings all over again.
Is there a way, some script or something, which could provide me with a possibility to save the export setting of the file, to the file itself - so whenever hitting export the setings for it would be remembered?

Comment: Maybe a script that does all the exporting for you would be a better option.